# Being able to answer closed question

Tags: feature-request, bug, closed-questions

I was able to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298544/recommended-os-for-programmers-closed) AFTER it was closed.

> closed as subjective and argumentative
>   by 280Z28, Kirtan, Greg, Neil
>   Butterworth, AraK 13 mins ago

And

> answered 12 mins ago smok1 1,775●1●13

---

Ok, I started answering before this question was closed. Don't you think it would be nice to have an ability to inform user that question for which he is now writing an answer was closed in meantime?

Comment: I personally think that answers already being composed should be allowed. When you're taking your time to write an answer it is very upsetting when the question is closed from underneath you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notification does exist, but I believe the check for new answers etc is done on a polling basis, e.g. once per minute. (I haven't checked what the actual timing is.) It's quite feasible for you to have posted your answer before your browser did the next poll.

EDIT: It's not clear to me whether that's still the case - I think it's on a more "push" basis these days. I could be wrong though.

Comment: So this is a client-based detection? What is the server grace period?

Comment: @hexafraction: This answer is over 4 years old. I think it's now all cunning web sockets etc.

Comment: Yet I still had this happen today to me.

Answer (score 7):

You should have gotten the same notification that pops up when you've been gunned down in a Fastest Gun in the West quick draw, McGraw.

Maybe you were able to hit the post button just before it was closing or on the edge.

Looking at the times:

```
Close time:  08:43:25
Your answer: 08:44:50
```

That's quite the shave.

Comment: The notification does not work all the time. Could be the issue here.

Comment: Or he could have gotten in just before the next cycle of polling disappointment.

Comment: this is correct; there is a topbar notification for both NEW ANSWERS and also QUESTION CLOSED