# Incorrectly able to answer a closed question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

The question, [What might you put in your own C#-like language?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2197356/revisions) was closed at **04:50**

And yet I was able to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2198299/revisions) at the time of **08:41** some four hours later.

The question was later reopened at **08:57**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four hours just about hits the top of the ceiling fan there for the grace period in [posting an answer on a question recently closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15388/being-able-to-answer-closed-question). Any longer and you'll be lockblocked.

It's there to allow slow pokes the time to finish off what they were answering on the off chance that the question will later be reopened.

Comment: It's probably infinite. As long as you start writing a reply before it gets closed you can post it. I think this is the way it should be.

Comment: But like everything on SOFU, there's always an upper limit. Just no idea what that is for closed questions getting answers. @kop

Comment: That view is awesome!

Comment: the grace period for answer submission is now 4 after after question closure; it is no longer 'infinite'.

Comment: Four wagon wheels? Four parsecs? You're making this game awfully unit vague @jeff

Comment: @random four wagon wheels! parsecs! tyrannosaurus rexes! sorry. hours.

Comment: **Note to self:** Open an "answer your question" window just in case the question gets closed.  Come back 3 hours later when I'm not busy.