# Editing my answer on a question that gets closed in the meantime

Tags: support, edits, closed-questions

Let's say I have submitted an answer to a question.

Then I spot something that could benefit from an edit.

Then I spot a typo. Then I spot something else with it, yet again.

You get the picture.

What happens when the question gets closed in the meantime?

1. Will I be able to send in my *ongoing* edit?
2. Will I be able to *initiate* a new edit, after the closing?
3. Are there different ways of closing that could exert differing effects in terms of 1. and 2., or will all ways of closings have the same impact on this behaviour?

---

**Note:**
I have found this question: [Submitting an answer to a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210295/908360), but it does not really help me, at least for the reason that it's so old and even then it seemed to be unclear / in a transitional state; plus the only upvoted answer is just sort of guesswork.

I would like to know how this works now.

Comment: You can always (unless it's [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)) edit your answers (and your questions) regardless of whether they're closed or not

Comment: Closing a question only prevents _new_ answers from being _posted_ (after [ca. 4 hours server-side](/q/210295/289905) ± caching).

Comment: So that suggests that the situation is way better now than as discussed in the old thread?

Comment: @Levente the old thread discusses *closing* after the 4 hour period, not editing after closing.

Comment: @Ollie I'm not sure I could follow that :D If you have the time, you could expand on that in your answer? (Optional!)

Comment: It's pretty simple: Everything you can do with your answer _before_ the question is closed, you can still do after it gets closed (that includes editing, deleting, undeleting, commenting, receiving votes, etc.)

Comment: @Ollie But what's that 4 hour thing for then? Ooooooh, it's here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364215/editing-my-answer-on-a-question-that-gets-closed-in-the-meantime#comment1215472_364215 Still new answers can be submitted within 4 hours from closing! Right? (And that has nothing to do with _already existing_ answers. Right?)

Comment: @Levente _That_ is a different question (which is answered in the post you linked to). Basically, in certain situations, you can get away with posting an answer shortly _after_ the question is closed. It's virtually impossible after 4 hours though. That doesn't seem to be related to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*I would like to know how this works now*" - It still works the same.  It doesn't matter if the question you answered is closed (after the publishing of said answer, that is).  You'll always be able to edit your own (unlocked) posts; the closing won't affect ongoing or later edits.

Comment: Might be worth noting that users without 10k rep (or 2k on beta sites) cannot edit answers on deleted questions