# The "working on it" proposal

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, closed-questions

It bothers me a lot when I'm spending some time and effort trying to answer a question only to learn it got closed for any reason. It's just a lot of time wasted. So I have come up with a solution for it:

1. Create a new button on questions called "Working on it".
2. The user is guaranteed 30 minutes to answer the question, even after it is closed.

This way, I think it is a greater motivation too to answer questions without the fear of having all my work wasted.

Comment: This already exists. The client enforces question closure immediately, but the server doesn't enforce it until four hours later.

Comment: But once the question is closed, I can't submit an answer anymore... what do you mean? @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog

Comment: @code Please check [Submitting an answer to a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210295/562482), and some of the linked posts shown on the right side.

Comment: If you get familiar with a network site's rules for what's on-topic, you will learn to spot when a question should be closed and avoid wasting time on it. If you're having trouble understanding why a specific question deserved to be closed, you can ask about it on that site's meta.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was an answer allowed on a question that was merged into another one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79457/282094)

Answer (score 16):

If a question warrants being closed then I do not think that an answer to it warrants being worked on.

Consequently, I think that any time available for submitting an answer after closure should be considered a “bonus” to those attempting to provide one.